# TFS Single File Checkin Permission

Tags: tfs, permissions, azure-devops, checkin

we are using TFS (2012) And i want to define one spesific file's check-in permission.
e.g.: Only administrator can change my config file, that file should be read only to others.

is it possible to fobid other users to check-in **spesific file** in the project?

Comment: try adding a lock to the file

Comment: can you be please more spesific? i'm kinda new.

Comment: sorry right click on the file in question and goto advanced and then click lock, this will prevent others from checking in.

Comment: i'm sorry, i dont have that properties. i need that file to be changed by only administrator. dont i need to do this on permission settings?

Answer (score 0):

You can either use a file lock as a temporary short term solution, or you can set the security for the individual file.

Right click on the file and then goto Advanced.

From here you can choose lock, or security.

[image: source file right click context menu]

using the Security window you can set the rights to check in or read as shown in the image below

[image: File Permissions]

If you don't have the rights to set the source control permissions then it may need to be set up by an Administrator